# Xvfb does not start second screen

Tags: linux, docker, xvfb, electron

I need a docker test-bed with multiple fake screens in an X server, according to the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xvfb) xvfb can launch multiple screens with multiple resolutions, but I only ever get screen 0.

An example directly from the man page is

> **Xvfb :1 -screen 1 1600x1200x16**
> The server will listen for connections as server number 1, will have the default screen configuration (one screen, 1280x1024x8), and screen 1 will be depth 16 1600x1200.

But I only get the default screen 0:

```sh
# xvfb-run -s '-screen 1 1600x1200x16' xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output screen
Screen 0: minimum 1 x 1, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 1280 x 1024
screen connected 1280x1024+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1280x1024      0.00*
```

Curiously, if I specify a frame buffer directory I can see it in the filesystem:

```
# mkdir -p /tmp/x && xvfb-run -s '-screen 1 1600x1200x16 -fbdir /tmp/x' ls /tmp/x
Xvfb_screen0  Xvfb_screen1
```

But that's useless to me without being able to see it in `xrandr` and `electron`.

Am I doing something wrong or does it just not work how I need it to?

Electron example:

```js
# echo "let { screen, app } = require('electron'); app.on('ready', () => setTimeout(()=>console.log(screen.getAllDisplays()) && app.quit(),1000))" > foo.js
# xvfb-run -s '-screen 0 800x600x8 -screen 1 1920x1080x16' electron --no-sandbox foo.js
// removed errors
[
  {
    id: 70,
    label: '',
    bounds: { x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 600 },
    workArea: { x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 600 },
    accelerometerSupport: 'unknown',
    monochrome: false,
    colorDepth: 8,
    colorSpace: '{primaries:BT709, transfer:SRGB, matrix:RGB, range:FULL}',
    depthPerComponent: 8,
    size: { width: 800, height: 600 },
    displayFrequency: 0,
    workAreaSize: { width: 800, height: 600 },
    scaleFactor: 1,
    rotation: 0,
    internal: false,
    touchSupport: 'unknown'
  }
]
```

**Edit**: this is in Docker containers running on Debian Buster & Ubuntu Jammy